# How to avoid inserting the unwanted values to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to insert only the selected value but when I save its inserting all the values in database.[image][image]

In the above database in `subject` column I want only the subject which has the faculty.But in my database all the subjects are inserting.

I am using `boundfield` for the subject column in `GridView`. My code so far`

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gvassignsubject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gvassignsubject_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="subject" SortExpression="subject" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Faculty">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID ="lblfaculty" runat="server" Text='<%%# Eval("facultyname") %>>' Visible="false"/>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfaculty" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Set Hour">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txthour" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>`


 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow r in Gvassignsubject.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Gvassignsubject.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string batch = ddlbatches.SelectedValue;
                    string subject = r.Cells[0].Text;
                    DropDownList ddlfaculty = (DropDownList)Gvassignsubject.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlfaculty");
                    TextBox txthour = (TextBox)Gvassignsubject.Rows[i].FindControl("txthour");
                    string facultyname = ddlfaculty.SelectedValue;
                    string sethour = txthour.Text;
                    con2.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into assign (batch,facultyname,sethour,subject)values(@batch,@facultyname,@sethour,@subject)", con2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", batch);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultyname", facultyname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sethour", sethour);
                    cmd.Connection = con2;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con2.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please put a check for ddlfaculty.SelectedValue like if(!(ddlfaculty.SelectedValue.ToString()=="Please Select") before assigning it to facultyname and doing the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Its adding all the rows regardless because you have no criteria;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Gvassignsubject.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        DropDownList ddlfaculty = (DropDownList)Gvassignsubject.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlfaculty");
        string facultyname = ddlfaculty.SelectedValue;

        if (!string.Equals(ddlfaculty.SelectedValue, "Please Select"))
        {
            string batch = ddlbatches.SelectedValue;
            string subject = r.Cells[0].Text;
            TextBox txthour = (TextBox)Gvassignsubject.Rows[i].FindControl("txthour");
            string sethour = txthour.Text;
            con2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into assign (batch,facultyname,sethour,subject)values(@batch,@facultyname,@sethour,@subject)", con2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", batch);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultyname", facultyname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sethour", sethour);
            cmd.Connection = con2;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con2.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this.but same output.Its showing all the subjects in database.Is there any alternate for foreach ?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case as the criteria will prevent is adding rows with a default drop down list value, have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see if it is doing what you require?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to set default select list item value as `null` and check for it in your `for` loop:

`for (int i = 0; i < Gvassignsubject.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlfaculty.SelectedValue)) {
    ...
   }
}`

Comment: Can you say what is `ddlfaculty.SelectedValue` value in loop for rows you don't want to insert to DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition that will check the value exist or not in the subject field.  You can do this like below :

`if(facultyname !="" && facultyname !="Please Select")
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into assign (batch,facultyname,sethour,subject)values(@batch,@facultyname,@sethour,@subject)", con2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", batch);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultyname", facultyname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sethour", sethour);
                    cmd.Connection = con2;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`

This is considering the condition that the ddlfaculty dropdown 
                  has the Value same as its Text.

Comment: this is not working,same result. Is there any alternate for foreach ?

Comment: Can you please suggest what is the value of the facultyname , where `  string facultyname = ddlfaculty.SelectedValue;`
when it has no value in the database?

Comment: facultyname is selected from dropdownlist (ddlfaculty)

Comment: @KevinAndrid  can you please suggest  that the  value of _ddlfaculty.SelectedValue_ when it is showing _"Please Select"_ on the datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(ddlfaculty.selectedindex !=-1 )
{
do the insert function
}
```